# Creating Dynamic Username Link, which will redirect to user profile

Tags: php, html, ajax

This might be very basic question, but I wonder how can I implement this usign PHP and Ajax or with any suggested scripting language.

I want to dynamically generate a link which will open the user profile page, would anyone suggest the best approach for it.

Thanks in advance for your responce

Comment: Are you going to show code for what you have tried and explain why it is not working?

Answer (score 4):

Generally, a dynamic link looks something like this:

```
mysite.com/user.php?id=23
```

Then, on `user.php` you would have something like this:

```
if (!isset($_GET['id']))
    die("No user information!!");
else {
    $user_id = $_GET['id'];
    // Now use $id to query the database and get user information
}
```

To generate the link on another page, you would just do something like this:

```
<a href="user.php?id=<?=$user_id?>">My Profile Page</a>
```

Where `$user_id` is the currently logged in user's id